# Why Emacs cursor movement key is chosen such a way?

Tags: emacs

My question is simple. As a newcomer I find it confusing to use Emacs movement keys.

So I am curious to know why Emacs have chosen its movement key such a way?

```
Up → C-p
Down → C-n
Left → C-f
Right → C-b
```

It could have been keys from single line. Why was it chosen this way?

Comment: Probably because it's easy to remember: *previous (line), next (line), forward, backward*. This'll also show you immediately that you confused `C-f` and `C-b`.

Comment: good point. That should be an answer too @DanielBeck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It for two reasons, the keyboard emacs was designed for (see photo), and then the letters of the movement keys are based on the first letter of the command.

> 【Ctrl+p】   previous-line
>
> 【Ctrl+n】   next-line
>
> 【Ctrl+b】   backward-char
>
> 【Ctrl+f】   forward-char

[source](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_kb_shortcuts_pain.html)
[image]

Comment: 1. I don't see what's different about the arrangement of f,b,n,p on this keyboard compared to any other qwerty keyboard. 2. You're using Xah Lee as a credible source? Seriously?

Comment: @ThePhoton Well, they do source their sources (which also source theirs), and when I read those sources, they seems legitimate/plausible to this humble vi user.

Comment: @ThePhoton Sometimes Xah Lee isn't wrong. Rare as such cases are, I'd suggest this is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

In the Xah Lee essay linked by @demure, there's a quote from Dan Weinreb explaining the origin of the keybindings:

> At the time Guy Steele put together the Emacs default key mappings, many people in the target user community (about 20 people at MIT!) were already using these key bindings. It would have been hard to get the new Emacs bindings accepted by the community if they differed for such basic commands.

I don't believe the position of `Ctrl` and `Meta` on the Symbolics keyboard influenced this decision, because according to Wikipedia,

> The original Emacs, like TECO, ran only on the PDP line of computers.